# PHP in_array not performing correctly

Tags: php, arrays

So I have this

```
            $changed = $_POST;
            if(in_array("op1", $changed))
            {
                echo 'Yes';
            } else
            {
                echo 'No';
            }
```

Everytime I run this it just says no...

If I print my POST though like this..

```
print_r($_POST);
```

it shows my array looks like this

```
Array ( [search] => [op1] => Yes [submit] => Submit Query ) No
```

So I can see that OP1 is there but the `if(in_array)` is NOT working.

Comment: In_array used for value search not key search

Answer (score 7):

The `in_array` looks for *values* in the array. You are trying to search for a key.

You want to use `array_key_exists` instead.

http://php.net/array_key_exists

```
if(array_key_exists("op1", $changed)) {
```

Comment: Or possibly `isset($_POST['op1'])` if nulls are not an issue

Comment: Unless `$_POST['op1']` is not `NULL`.

Comment: So if I am searching for a key, For instance I just changed my code to if(in_array("Yes", $changed)) and it worked because yes is in there. How do I match the key to the value found though? If it found YES... How does it know that YES came from the key of op1?

Comment: @RoxyMiles `if(array_key_exists("op1", $changed) && $changed['op1'] == "Yes")` like that

Comment: @RoxyMiles checking to see if the key exists, and checking the value of that key are two separate operations. But easily combined with `&&`.

Comment: I will answer it in 8 minutes when it lets me.. In the mean time I have one more question.. Is there a dynamic way to search for more then one key at a time? for instance if I wanted to do if(array_key_exists)("op1-op24", $changed)  Obviously not like that but I think you get what I mean? :) Ty

Comment: @RoxyMiles Not quite, but you can do it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) used for searching value from given array,but you want to search key of array So you may use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/array_key_exists) for searching array key

```
 if(array_key_exists("op1", $changed)) {
     echo 'Yes';
 } else {
     echo 'No';
 }
```